# Counting files containing all of the matching strings, i.e. AND operator?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to count all text files in a folder that contains all strings in a set of strings, i.e. basically an AND-operator. The order of the string in each file may way and preferably I'm looking for a one-liner.

I.e. I'm trying to accomplish something like:

```
(Get-ChildItem -filter "file*" C:\temp |
Select-String -Pattern @(“str1", "str2")).Count
```

but with the difference that the above statement counts all files containing either "str1" or "str2" but I'm trying to do an AND-operation instead of an OR, thus count only files that contains both "str1" and "str2".

Regards, Ola

Comment: I did solve the problem using the MultiSelect-String found in at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920383/how-to-use-powershell-select-string-to-find-more-than-one-pattern-in-a-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This perhaps can do the job with a `-AND` operator :

```
(Get-ChildItem . -include *.txt -recurse |
    % {(Select-String $_ -Pattern "str1") -AND (select-string $_ -pattern "str2")} |
        where {$_ -eq $true}).count
```

Answer (score 2):

If the number of input strings is fixed, then it can be done quite neatly by taking advantage of the pipeline:

```
get-childitem c:\temp\file* |
    select-string -l str1   |
    get-childitem           |
    select-string -l str2   |
    measure-object
```

If you want to get just the count, rather than the statistics that `Measure-Object` returns, add `| select -exp Count` to the end of the pipeline.

I find it useful to add the following to my `$profile` in order to reduce this sort of thing even more.

```
Set-Alias ss Select-String
${function:...} = { process { $_.($args[0]) } }
```

Then, the solution (assuming default aliases) becomes:

```
gci c:\temp\file* | ss -l str1 | gci | ss -l str2 | measure | ... Count
```

References: [Power and Pith - Windows PowerShell Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/10/21/power-and-pith.aspx)

Comment: How will this work? The downstream select-string's are on the previous ones and not on the files.

Comment: Ahhh, you're right. It needs a little help with intermediate `get-childitem` calls. Sorry about that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: With the correction this works nice too so I wish I could accept both as answer.

Comment: @OlaTheander Thanks! It's not possible to accept both answers, I'm afraid, but I appreciate the sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge this can't be done prettily. So maybe something like this (untested):

```
@(Get-ChildItem |
    Where-Object {
      $failed = $false
      $file = Get-Content $_
      $strings | ForEach-Object {
        if (!($file -match $_)) { $failed = $true }
      }
      !$failed
    }).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@(Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Filter "file*" | 
  where { ($_ | Select-String str1 -Quiet) -and ($_ | Select-String str2 -Quiet)}
).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe a Get-ChildItem command into a Where-Object filter that accepts a RegEx pattern, and then count the Outputs.
The command would look like this:

```
(Get-ChildItem . | Where{$_.Name -Match "<RegEx Pattern>"}).count
```

The Name attribute will match the name of the file or folder, along with a file's extension,and the RegEx Patter can handle the matching to your liking.