# How to get files which have multiple required strings

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find the files which have given strings. I am using the below line

```
 Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "Magnet","Stew" | group path | select name
```

But it is giving the files which are having any one of the words "Magnet","Stew". But I want the files which have both the words. In logically speaking the above command interprets it as "Or" condition. I want "And" condition. Can anybody guide me of how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use PowerShell select-string to find more than one pattern in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920383/how-to-use-powershell-select-string-to-find-more-than-one-pattern-in-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your regex:

```
'.*(?:stew.*magnet)|(?:magnet.*stew).*'
```

Edit:

If you're looking for those matches anywhere in the file:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
 where {(
          ($_ | Select-String -Pattern 'Stew' -SimpleMatch -Quiet) -and
          ($_ | Select-String -Pattern 'Magnet' -SimpleMatch -Quiet)
         )}
```

The solution posted at the link CB provided will work, but doesn't seem very efficient for what you're needing to do.  The `-SimpleMatch` will be faster than using a Regex pattern, and the `-Quiet` switch will make it just return True or False, depending on whether it found a match in the file.  If one or the other of the terms is much less likely to appear in the file, change the order so that one appears first in the test stack so the test will fail sooner and it can move on to the next file.

Comment: I think that can be a problem if the two words are in different lines.

Comment: You're right.  If it's anywhere in the file, then select-string isn't going to be a good fit for the solution if you want to do it in one read operation.

Comment: Maybe using `[system.io.file]::ReadAllText()` can be done, it always returns a string type.

Comment: Or Get-Content -Raw, and change the regex to multi-line.  But you could run into memory issues with large files.