# Find multiple strings in text files powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to create a script that searches through a folders and subfolders searching all the text files for 2 strings. If a file is found then it copys this to another folder. I'm able to do it for 1 string but i can't seem to figure out a way to do an AND in it. (Using -and in the select-string doesnt seem to work)

This is what I have so far(Quite sure the -or doesn't work)

```
$user = "domain\username"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server -ScriptBlock { 
Get-ChildItem -recurse -Include *.txt  -path "File Location" | 
Select-String -pattern ("TAX=1+005+0950" -or "TAX=1+5+0950+0") -SimpleMatch  |  
Copy-Item -Destination "Destination Location"
} -credential $user
```

I'm needing to search for either of the ones in the code above AND either of these 2 `"TAX=1+5+0600" "TAX=1+005+0600"`

Any idea how I can do this?

So basically I want to be able to do

```
Select-String -pattern (TAX=1+005+0950 OR TAX=1+5+0950+0) AND (TAX=1+005+0600 OR TAX=1+5+0600)
```

Comment: Are you saying that you need to find the existence of one from BOTH lists, or just one from any of the four?  That would imply needing an `-and` (actually a `&`) but I'm not sure if you don't just need another `-or` instead (actually a `|`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PowerShell select-string to find more than one pattern in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920383/how-to-use-powershell-select-string-to-find-more-than-one-pattern-in-a-file)

Comment: Yeah it needs to find 1 from the first list and 1 from the second.

Also it's not a duplicated of the above, the above is for either OR or if ones comes after the other.

Comment: Actually, if you read the answers, you'll see that they fit your needs exactly.  They do two consecutive, piped, `select-string` commands, one from the first list, and one from the second.

Comment: Yes but then how do I do an -OR statement?
E.G 
    where { $_ | Select-String -Pattern 'TAX=1+005+0950' -or      'TAX=1+5+0950' } |
      where { $_ | Select-String -Pattern 'TAX=1+005+0600' -or 'TAX=1+5+0600' } |

This doesn't work

Comment: As I mentioned above, I believe you intended to use `|` and `&` not `-or` and `-and`  -  Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4629411/2486496) to see the correct syntax for using `or` conditions.

Comment: where { $_ | Select-String -Pattern '(TAX=1+005+0950)|(TAX=1+5+0950)' } |
  where { $_ | Select-String -Pattern '(TAX=1+005+0600)|(TAX=1+5+0600)' } |

Still does not work

Comment: Your syntax is still not correct, as you can't follow a `|` with a `where` statement like that... again, look at the answers for that question, and you should see exactly what to do.  There are countless similar questions and many options available to achieve this.