# moving an xml file based on multiple search strings

Tags: powershell

still learning powershell. I have a script that moves an xml file based on a search string but it needs to match more than 1 search string and I'm struggling with a way to do this.

Here's the code as I have it, which currently works for a single string:

```
$SrcDir = "c:\source"
$DestDir = "c:\destination"
$SearchString1 = "String1"
$SearchString2 = "String2"

Get-ChildItem $SrcDir -filter *.xml | 
  Select-String $SearchString1 -List | 
  Select-Object Path | 
  Move-Item -Dest $DestDir
```

So it's clear what I'm trying to achieve: If the xml file contains `$SearchString1` AND `$SearchString2` then move from source to destination. I can't seem to make it match both. It's probably very simple, or maybe I need to do it a different way, but I would appreciate some help.

Comment: As `Get-Help Select-String` says, this cmdlet accepts Regular Expressions. So why not `Select-String -Pattern "($SearchString1|$SearchString2)"` to make it quite simple?

Comment: The better soultion for this special case would be `"String(1|2)"` (or similiar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PowerShell select-string to find more than one pattern in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920383/how-to-use-powershell-select-string-to-find-more-than-one-pattern-in-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1)'s help:

```
PS> Get-Help Select-String -Parameter Pattern
```

> -Pattern
>
> Specifies the text to find. Type a string or regular expression. If you type a string, use the SimpleMatch parameter.
>
> To learn about regular expressions, see [about_Regular_Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-5.1).

It says, that `-Pattern` wants a reqular expression, not a `[string]`. As suggested by the help page, we learn more about Regular Expressions using [`Get-Help About_Regular_Expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-5.1).

This results in replacing your statement `Select-String $SearchString1 -List` with:

```
Select-String "($SearchString1.*$SearchString2|$SearchString2.*$SearchString1)" -List | #[...]
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, this is much closer, as it now searches against both strings, however it uses OR rather than AND, so it moves it if it matches either rather than both. 

Also, thanks for the link, it will come in handy while I'm learning.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the and... this is hard using regex. For this I'd recommend you to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4629411/4068240)

Comment: That didn't move anything at all, but the other answer is indeed what I'm trying to do so I'll work from that and see what I can come up with and post back, thank you for your assistance!  I did search but not with 'pattern' as I've not come across that term in powershell before. was searching for 'match multiple strings' which wasn't giving me anything useful